# Entry processes Limit, 508 error on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress installation on a server since 3 months and i haven't had any problems since then. two days ago pingdom checked my site and realized it was down, so i went to check and i got the famous 508 error. 
i've put my site in maintenance mode as it's completely down as soon as 20-30 people are online.

I checked cpanel and i have 20/20 Entry processes.

I tried updating all plugins but with no success. My hosting provider didn't explain me anything usable so please someone help me :-(

[Entry process usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3OHx.png)

[CPU, EP and Faults  graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBUy1.png)

if you need some information i will be pleased to answer, i need my website back :-)

Comment: It could potentially be malware, using up a lot of your allocated memory. It's certainly not uncommon with Wordpress.

Comment: how can a malware be in my wordpress installation? maybe with a plugin i installed? i have only a few plugins and i haven't installed new ones lately..

Comment: WP can be hacked - I recently found someone had found a loophole in phpMyAdmin and set a new password for a WP admin account, and then used Plugins > Editor to add some code to a plugin. It may [look like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799429/is-this-a-wordpress-virus) (also see the comment there for a link on how to deal with possible infections of WP). You could download the site via (S)FTP to examine it locally. Or, you could start disabling plugins until the site behaves normally again.

Comment: There are a few steps I would take. Make a clean install of the latest version of wordpress, and clean install your plugins either from wordpress or "working" backups if you have them. Check your database for unknown accounts and delete them.

Comment: ok thanks. i will check for modified/added users and then i will try disabling plugins to see if i find the broken one. Hope it is not a virus...

Comment: i tried disabling the theme but still have high entry process, but not as high as yesterday. This high ep started exactly 6 days ago. is there a way to check some logs to see if there were some modifications that day?

Comment: nothing... disabled all plugins and completely deleted theme... What can i do now?